# MySQL Exporting query output to CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, export

[MySQL Workbench 6.2 on Windows7]

I can export the query results clicking in the MySQL workbench export icon. See image below:

[image: Manual way to export query results to csv files]

However, I need to do this repeatedly in different loops, so I would like to include it in my script.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where ID = 123456 INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I also tried the filepath with `\\` instead of `/`, and also with `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r \n'` as I have seen in other posts.

When I tried this, I get `Permission Denied [Errcode 13]` despite I have grated my user file permissions in the MySQL command client too with the following code:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE User = 'db_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Any ideas why it is still not working? Any good alternative is also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to folder access permission for mysql. So use below path to write csv file.

```
C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
```

Let suppose your system has user name ABC then your query should be.

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where ID = 123456 INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Miya G. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error :/

Comment: Here it is `Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\foldername\outfiletest.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`

Comment: Still you are not using right path as described in above answer. e.g. `C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp`

Comment: I am using the \\ in my script, it appears as \ in the error :S

Comment: Have you set outfile path to `Temp` folder?

Comment: I haven't set the path to Temp. I tried 'testfile.csv' in the path name and it seems it saved the query output, but I cannot find it! I am reading that it may be stored somewhere in the server. I installed the server in my desktop too, but I am not very experience on it. How should I set the outfile path to Temp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66146/discussion-between-miya-g-and-user3507584).